# Using a transparent version of Accent Color

Tags: android, xml, colors

I am trying to use multiple transparent variations of my accent color in my xml (10%, 50%, ... etc).

Example of my current code:

```
<color name="colorAccent">#FF0000</color>
<color name="colorAccent10Percent">#1AFF0000</color>
<color name="colorAccent50Percent">#80FF0000</color>
```

I was wondering if there is an easier way than setting a new color for each transparency, so that whenever I change the color accent all the dependant colors would change automatically. This is what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
<color name="colorAccent">#FF0000</color>
<color name="colorAccent10Percent" alpha="0.1">@color/colorAccent</color>
<color name="colorAccent50Percent" alpha="0.5">@color/colorAccent</color>
```

Changing the views' alpha is not an option though.